# Speed up a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, kernel-density

I am using the following function to estimate the Kernel density of some data

```
KDens = function(x,h,N) {
         fx = matrix(0,N,1)
         Kx = AK(x,h,N)
         for (i in 1:N) {
         fx[i] = sum(Kx[i,], na.rm=T)/N
         }
         return(fx) }
```

I know this is not the first question about speeding up a loop. I checked around in the site, I found that sometimes using some `apply` function is faster, but this is not always the case if you manage to correctly set the loop.

In the above code, every "not needed thing" is left out of the loop, as - if I understood correctly - suggested to speed up computation. However, I made a comparison between the above `KDens` function and the `density` function implemented in R by default. Well, `density` needs 1 or 2 seconds, while `KDens` needs ~30 on my machine.

```
trywiththis <- rnorm(4800)
x = trywiththis
N = length(trywiththis)
h = 1.059*sd(trywiththis , na.rm=T)*(N^(-0.2))
```

EDIT: the information I provided was not complete

```
kerf = function(x){ return(dnorm(x)) }
ker = function(x,x0,h){
       temp = kerf((x-x0)/h)/h
       return(temp)
       }

AK = function(x,h,N) {
      K = array(0,c(N,N))                 
         for (i in 1:N) {
         for (j in 1:N) {
         K[i,j] = ker(x[i],x[j],h) 
       }}
       return(K) }
```

Suppose I want to speed up the KDens function, how could I do that ?

Comment: Try `rowSums` .

Comment: As in `fx <- rowSums( Kx ) / N` without the `for` loop (and you won't need to pre-allcoate `fx` either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this... For your original 4800 length dataset it takes 2.5 seconds.

```
KDens2 = function(x,h,N) {
Kx <- outer( x , x , FUN = function(x,y) dnorm( ( x-y ) / h ) / h )
fx <- as.matrix( rowSums( Kx ) / N , ncol = 1 )
return( fx )
}
```

#### Testing

```
set.seed(1)
trywiththis <- rnorm(480)
x = trywiththis
N = length(trywiththis)
h = 1.059*sd(trywiththis , na.rm=T)*(N^(-0.2))

#Produce same result? (posibly not identical because of 'dnorm' function)
all.equal( KDens(x,h,N) , KDens2(x,h,N) )
[1] TRUE

#Rough timing on N=480 length data...
system.time( KDens2(x,h,N) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.00    0.02 

system.time( KDens(x,h,N) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#    2.7     0.0     2.7
```

And when `N=4800`...

```
system.time( KDens2(x,h,N) )
   user  system elapsed 
   2.33    0.19    2.51
```

Comment: If I understood properly, with KDens2 I will not need neither `kerf`, nor `ker`, nor `AK`.
These are my tests: `system.time( KDens2(z1,h1,N=n) )
   user  system elapsed 
   4.52    0.21    4.72 
> system.time( KDens(z1,h1,N=n) )
   user  system elapsed 
 273.69    0.04  273.98`

Comment: @Bob correct! `KDens2` should be the only function you need. I rolled up the functionality of the others into a single function. HTH.

Comment: It helps a lot. I will try to apply the principle you suggested to other 2 functions which are similar to KDens. Hope to succeed at it. Thank you